# how to restart unicorn manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

I'm not confident that unicorn is restarting properly when I run `cap deploy` as certain changes are not showing in the app, therefore I wanted to restart unicorn manually on my remote server. I have navigated into `etc/init.d` and see a listing for `unicorn_myapp` but it's not a directory (i.e. I can't cd into it).  Based on the code below from my deploy.rb file, is there something I can do from here to restart unicorn?

I tried to do `run unicorn_myapp restart` but it said `run` isn't a command

```
namespace :deploy do
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
    end
  end
```

Comment: FYI the answers on here are all wrong.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you didn't list the OS.  but one of the following should work.

you will need to be root / use sudo

```
/etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp restart 


/etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp stop 
/etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp start 


service unicorn_myapp restart

service unicorn_myapp stop
service unicorn_myapp start
```

Try the restart versions first, but depending upon how the init script was written it might not have a restart command,  if that doesn't work you can do the stop / start version.

Answer (score 28):

Alternatively, instead of relying on `/etc/init.d...` scripts which are OS dependent, a simple way to restart unicorn is to send `HUP (1)` signal to its master process.

Here is for instance how I reload an app automatically after a `git push` via `post-receive` hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
unicorn_pid=`cat /tmp/pids/unicorn.pid`
echo "Restarting Unicorn ($unicorn_pid)"
kill -HUP $unicorn_pid
```

In your case, `/etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp restart` script is probably doing this. Check the unicorn.conf for the location of its pidfile.

For more details, see [unicorn SIGNALS documentations](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/SIGNALS.html)

Comment: fyi, relative `tmp/pids...` path was intentional and not a typo... my git hook being run in project path holding a local `tmp` folder... Anyway! :)

Comment: It requires a process id also after 
    `kill -HUP $unicorn_pid <running PID>`

Answer (score 6):

You might have to be root, but it should just be `/etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp restart` (don't include `run`, which is not a shell command).