# Deploying a legacy Rails 2.3 application on a shared host and facing sudo access error

Tags: deployment, shared-hosting, ruby-on-rails-2, ruby-1.9.3, capistrano3

I have a legacy application built with Rails 2.3.2. I need to deploy this application using Capistrano to a shared host. I am using latest stable version of capistrano which is 3.3.5. Below you can find the specific versions being used:

```
Ruby 1.9.3-p551
Ruby Gems 1.5.3
Rails 2.3.2
Capistrano (3.3.5)
```

I am facing following error (detailed logs can be found in the [gist](https://gist.github.com/jiggneshhgohel/3dae4ea30f4634e41eed) here):

```
    INFO [e00fcb66] Running /usr/bin/env sudo /etc/init.d/unicorn_cebucondo_production restart as cebucond@106.186.120.245
    DEBUG [e00fcb66] Command: ( PATH=/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/git:$PATH /usr/bin/env sudo /etc/init.d/unicorn_cebucondo_production restart )
    DEBUG [e00fcb66]    stdin: is not a tty
    DEBUG [e00fcb66]    sudo:
    DEBUG [e00fcb66]    effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?
    (Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
    cap aborted!
    SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as cebucond@106.186.120.245: sudo exit status: 1
    sudo stdout: Nothing written
    sudo stderr: stdin: is not a tty
    sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?
    /CCL/lib/capistrano/tasks/restart.cap:6:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /CCL/lib/capistrano/tasks/restart.cap:5:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
    SSHKit::Command::Failed: sudo exit status: 1
    sudo stdout: Nothing written
    sudo stderr: stdin: is not a tty
    sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?
    /CCL/lib/capistrano/tasks/restart.cap:6:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /CCL/lib/capistrano/tasks/restart.cap:5:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
    Tasks: TOP => deploy:restart
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as cebucond@106.186.120.245: sudo exit status: 1
    sudo stdout: Nothing written
    sudo stderr: stdin: is not a tty
    sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?
```

I do not have the sudo access on the shared host and neither it can be provided to my user as it is a shared hosting environment as per update from shared host support team. Also it is strange that I am not using any specific server to serve my application on my remote host but still capistrano tries to run Unicorn script as can be seen in the log below and which in fact needs sudo access and hence failing.

```
 INFO [e00fcb66] Running /usr/bin/env sudo /etc/init.d/unicorn_cebucondo_production restart as cebucond@106.186.120.245
```

Here is the [link](https://gist.github.com/jiggneshhgohel/4e90ec4acf937074c248) to my `deploy.rb` file and here is the [link](https://gist.github.com/jiggneshhgohel/403a6d4870b18bb4c59b) to my `Capfile`.

Please note that my application doesn't use Bundler so it doesn't have any Gemfile and the gems used are placed in app's `vendor/plugins` folder.

Can anybody please provide your inputs on how to get rid of the errors being encountered and make the deployment successful?

Thanks,
Jiggneshh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have root access to the machine you are unlikely to be able to [re]start unicorn using anything in `/etc/init.d`.

Whichever plugin, or whichever of your own tasks is defining the line that reads `sudo /etc/init.d/unicorn_cebucondo_production restart` will have to be changed or removed, and ideally would try to restart unicorn using a [signal](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/SIGNALS.html), which may be allowed, or more likely you will have to have a [`setuid`](http://www.tuxation.com/setuid-on-shell-scripts.html) wrapper script which allows you to perform *one* action as root.

Capistrano has never been supported on shared hosts, for exactly these reasons.

There are many, many things that can be done to make it possible for you to restart unicorn, in this case however I might really suggest that you look at *Passenger*.

You may find more wisdom on the many other SO posts about how to restart unicorn, for example [how to restart unicorn manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352125/how-to-restart-unicorn-manually)

Comment: Thanks Lee.I realised about what you said after creating the post and looking at the `deploy.rb` file wherein following hook `after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'` was enabled which provided a hint that `deploy:restart` might be issuing Unicorn restart command and I commented it out and voila the deployment was successful. But still I have a question: Does Capistrano by default tries to run unicorn script even though I didn't set any executable config files `set(:executable_config_files, [])`?

Comment: We don't do anything like that, maybe some plugins that you have loaded will, it's impossible to tell, we don't maintain them all.