# Redmine plugins are not shows

Tags: mariadb, unicorn, god

CentOS 7, nginx+unicorn+god+mariadb. I'm trying to install plugins, but unable to do it. Creating tmp/restart.txt didnot helped and restarting nginx too. Any other ideas why? Please help.
Environment:

Redmine version            2.6.1.stable

Ruby version                  2.0.0-p598 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux]

Rails version                  3.2.21

Environment                   production

Database adapter               Mysql2

Gems:

- actionmailer (3.2.21)
- actionpack (3.2.21)
- activemodel (3.2.21)
- activerecord (3.2.21)
- activeresource (3.2.21)
- activesupport (3.2.21)
- arel (3.0.3)
- builder (3.0.4)
- bundler (1.13.1)
- coderay (1.1.1)
- erubis (2.7.0)
- hike (1.2.3)
- htmlentities (4.3.1)
- i18n (0.6.11)
- journey (1.0.4)
- jquery-rails (3.1.4)
- json (1.8.3)
- kgio (2.10.0)
- mail (2.5.4)
- mime-types (1.25.1)
- multi_json (1.12.1)
- mysql2 (0.3.21)
- net-ldap (0.3.1)
- polyglot (0.3.5)
- rack (1.4.7)
- rack-cache (1.6.1)
- rack-openid (1.4.2)
- rack-ssl (1.3.4)
- rack-test (0.6.3)
- rails (3.2.21)
- railties (3.2.21)
- raindrops (0.17.0)
- rake (11.3.0)
- rbpdf (1.18.7)
- rdoc (3.12.2)
- redcarpet (2.3.0)
- request_store (1.0.5)
- rmagick (2.16.0)
- ruby-openid (2.3.0)
- sprockets (2.2.3)
- thor (0.19.1)
- tilt (1.4.1)
- treetop (1.4.15)
- tzinfo (0.3.51)
- unicorn (5.1.0)

Comment: Got any error messages?  Check the logs?  What process did you use you do the plugins?  What plugins; those Gems, or other things, too?

Comment: Hello. Wich logs shall I to check? Plugins are http://www.redmine.org/plugins/redmine_workload and http://www.redmine.org/plugins/redmine_better_gantt_chart. What your mean by processes? It seems like god gem is missing, but it's showing in ps ax command output. How?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a tmp/restart.txt  does not apply to **Unicorn** server, it applies to **PhusionPassenger**, which checks for timestamp of restart.txt file, and if timestamp differs from the one it checked during it's startup, a restart of PhusionPassenger's application is applied, see its documentation [here](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/apache/restart_app.html#restart-txt).

To properly install Redmine plugins, you need to follow each plugin's installation tutorial, and apply server restart, in case of unicorn, you can see this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352125/how-to-restart-unicorn-manually), once you have restarted Unicorn, then

1. Login to Redmine as administrator
2. Navigate to **Administration | Plugins**
3. Configure plugin if necessary

Sometimes to be used, plugins needs to be enabled on per-project basis. To enable/disable plugins, 
navigate to your **project | Settings | Modules** and there you will be able to enable/disable plugins on per-project basisi.